# Refine a regex with group and lookaround

Tags: regex, pcre

I have the following pattern:

```
NAME         FISCAL 20394
```

I need to figure out whether or not after the name field is the owner's first and last name, or, for example, a company name, and if present, extract the data.

I report some explanatory examples:

```
NAME  MARY POPPINS       FISCAL 20394
NAME  MARY JANE POPPINS       FISCAL 20394
NAME  SNOWFLAKE INC.       FISCAL 20394
```

I've tried with the following regex:

```
NAME ([A-Za-z0-9]).*(?=FISCAL)
```

but in this case I am only able to recognize if there is text between NAME and FISCAL but not to extract (via group) the whole name (regardless of whether it consists of one or more words).

Would you be able to help me refine the regex?

Comment: Try: `NAME\h+(.+?)\h+FISCAL` and grab capture group #1

Comment: Hi Wictor,      in case of NAME         FISCAL 20394 i still have a match

Comment: Try: `NAME\h+([a-zA-Z].*?)\h+FISCAL`

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
NAME\s+\K\S.*?(?=\s+FISCAL\b)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/F8xV2b/1). Or, if you can do with a group:

```
NAME\s+(\S.*?)\s+FISCAL\b
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/F8xV2b/2).

*Details*:

- `NAME` - a literal string
- `\s+` - one or more whitespaces
- `(\S.*?)` - Group 1: a non-whitespace and then zero or more chars other than line break chars as few as possible
- `\s+` - one or more whitespaces
  -`FISCAL` - a fixed text
- `\b` - word boundary.